# Как вызвать приложение для построения маршрута в мобильной версии?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите, что не правильно я делаю для вызова приложения и передачи координат:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  var main = function() {
      var counter = 0;
      $('.half-map-brovary').click(function() {
          counter++;
          if (counter == 1) {
            $('.map-2').animate({
              left: '10px'
            }, 400);
            $('body').animate({
              left: '0px'
            }, 400);
          }
          if (counter == 2) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:50.5096716, 30.7901435"); startActivity(intent);
            }
          }); $('.half-map-kyiv').click(function() {
          $('.map-2').animate({
            left: '-180px'
          }, 600);
          $('body').animate({
            left: '0px'
          }, 600);
        });
      };
      $(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден (все оказалось куда проще чем думал)
Просто вставляем ссылку с браузера google maps при клике:

Например:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".direction").on("click", function() {
          window.open("https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0,+12,+%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2,+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,+02000/@50.5065367,30.5840678,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x40d4d1a5806b5feb:0x4698b18388b260a2!8m2!3d50.5065367!4d30.5862565", "_blank");
        });
</script>
```

И в мобильной версии предлагает вариант проложить маршрут, проедварительно выбрав приложение для этого.